# Add an element to a hook with a FrontController

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I am currently developing a **prestashop module** where the user can add as many visual elements (an accordion) as he wishes. I finished the configuration of the back office with my own database, everything is ok on that side.

The problem comes from the fact that depending on the hook chosen by the user (displayHome or a custom hook) the visual element will be added to it.

During my testing phases, I managed to display the corresponding visual rendering on the displayHome hook, via this method in my **main file** :

```php
public function hookDisplayHome($params) 
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            //...
        ]);

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'my_file.tpl');
    }
```

[The prestashop documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/#accessing-a-module-front-controller) for the FrontController explains how to configure it for visual rendering **on a custom page**, but nothing related to hooks.

I tried a similar process with the ***initContent()*** method but it doesn't seem to work.

I think that ***if()*** will be enough to assign the variables to different places according to the choice of the user. But if I can't just display it, I won't be able to think about it anyway.

How to interact with hooks via the FrontController ?

Comment: Did you try to put the corresponding method in the front controller ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work

Comment: Since your controller will display a custom page, it won't call the `displayHome` hook, you should call that hook from your module main file